# Convert datetime to specified format in c#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert 'yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss' format like 17/07/18 06:30:20 to Jul.18, 2017 06:30:20 in c#. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Pick one or build your own: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @mxmissile MS have a new one, i think it is a better one -  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Are you starting with a `string` or a `DateTime`?  `DateTime` does not _have_ a format, it only gets one when you _display_ it, so it's not clear from the question what you're starting with (and the answer will be different)

Comment: Sorry for the bad title but the answer given by Aman worked for me. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` as shown below:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("17/07/18 06:30:20", "yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss", 
CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
).ToString("MMM. dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: Perfectly worked. Thanks a lot